# Show available intergers within range of 0000-9999

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code below

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['add_site'])){
   $req_fields = array('siteid');
   validate_fields($req_fields);
   if(empty($errors)){
     $p_siteid   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['siteid']));
     $query  = "INSERT INTO site_table (siteid)";
     $query .=" VALUES ("'{$p_siteid}')";

     if($db->query($query)){
       $session->msg('s',"Site Added ");
       redirect('site.php', false);
     } else {
       $session->msg('d',' Sorry failed to add!');
       redirect('site.php', false);
     }
   } else{
     $session->msg("d", $errors);
     redirect('site.php',false);
   }
 }
?>
```

But i wanted to add a function that will check my table and show only the first 5 possible numbers i could choose/use which is not exist on my table values.

or

automatically pre-select a value from the same range 0000-9999 which is not yet exist on my table values upon opening the form.

My form div is like this below..

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12">
  <form method="post" action="add_site.php">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">
           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></i>
          </span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="siteid" placeholder="Site Number">
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group clearfix">
        <button type="submit" name="add_site" class="btn btn-primary">Add Site</button>
      </div>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

So if my table already have a values of

```
id   siteid
1    0000
2    0001
3    0004
4    1000
5    2000
6    5555
7    0006
8    0010
```

So, i could only possibly select the first 5 values of

```
0002
0003
0005
0007
0008
```

which it isn't exist yet on my existing table values and show it on my div form for selection.

Or

pre-select the value `0002` upon opening of the dialog form.

Comment: This is the code for just the insertion right? In which part of the page you would like to get the 5 first ids from database? Have you tried anything until now? - Or do you mean upon the insertion you would like to get the 5 first (available) ids?

Comment: if it possible to get the first 5 available ids before insertion, it could have a dropdown list of the 5 possible ids.

Comment: You will have to do a query SELECT p_siteid FROM site_table LIMIT 5 (you can use order too) before the form and put the results in an array. After that in the form just show these results as options.

Comment: What i meant was the possible ids that wasn't available on my table.

Comment: If you want to get a clear answer you will have to make a clear question, so please edit your question describing better what is your problem and what are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: Edited done. Sorry for the unclear question.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to have a helper table that lists all possible values or lists the numbers from 0 - 9 and you combine the numbers through 3 self joins to have the range created. The reason is that sql cannot create something that does not exist.

If you have a helper table with all possible numbers from 0000 - 9999 in a field called siteid, then use a left join:

```
select ht.siteid
from helper_table ht 
left join site_table st on st.siteid=ht.siteid
where st.siteid is null
order by ht.siteid asc
limit 5
```

If the helper table contains the numbers 0 - 9 only, then you create a Cartesian join between them and do the left join on the result of the Cartesian join:

```
select concat(ht1.siteid, ht2.siteid, ht3.siteid, ht4.siteid) as siteid
from (helper_table ht1 join helper_table ht2 join helper_table ht3 join helper_table ht4)
left join site_table st on st.siteid=concat(ht1.siteid, ht2.siteid, ht3.siteid, ht4.siteid)
where st.siteid is null
order by concat(ht1.siteid, ht2.siteid, ht3.siteid, ht4.siteid) asc
limit 5
```

If you really insist on not having a helper table you can create the 0 - 9 records dynamically using unions, however, I do not really see the advantage in doing so.

Comment: It's fine, but in the context of PHP, it's entirely unnecessary however.

Comment: How about if it will automatically suggest the first id that's available within same range (0000-9999) upon showing the dialog. What function should i do to check the site table?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand your question.

Comment: Instead of showing the first 5 available IDs, it will shows automatically the first available ID. In my example, it will show the output value "0002" on my form.

Comment: Find the part of my code that limits the number of records to 5 and change it to retrieve only one. Or just fetch the first record from my output and discard the rest.